# C++ find words in string with if statments

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I have a text input from `cmd`. I want to be able to read the text and find key words. If key words are found, via list of if statements, do action. I know of `.find`, and after experimenting and a lot of research, I can't seem to make it work.

**Pseudo code**

```
Text in

if text has "thisword"

    do this

if text has "also maybe these words"

    do this

if text has "these other words"

    do this

etc ...
```

I know of `.find` and it's counterparts but after trying many different ways of using it, I can't figure it out.

Lastly I want to find, not only one word, but I want some if statements to need multiple words in order to trigger. I need if statements.

Comment: You realize that the question is too broad. Bottom line you want to detect certain patterns in your string. C++11 has a facility for this [`<regex>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)

Comment: You're not only new to C++, you're new to programming.  No shame in that, but why claim otherwise?

Comment: You should be more specific about what you have tried. Show us some code and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Not new. Just not fluent. I understood it was a broad question going in, but like I said, I've been experimenting with things and researching for a while and can't get or find the results I want. Oddly enough, finding certain words in a string using if statements, isn't floating around the internet too much. It's always .find with if statements nested. I'm using Using VSExpress2010. If what I want isn't doable, than please let me know. I'll rethink my strategy.

Comment: At least on the face of it, what you've described sounds so trivial it's unlikely anybody has bothered to describe it in isolation. It's a bit like looking for a tutorial on how to turn the page of a book or an encyclopedia of shoe-tying techniques.

Comment: Did you read any documentation like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::string text;

std::getline(std::cin, text);

if (text.find("thisword") != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "did one" << std::endl;
}
if (text.find("also maybe these words") != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "did two" << std::endl;
}
if (text.find("these other words") != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "did three" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This wont work if the words are not together in the string, you should mention that. Still a valid answer if you make that assumption so you should state it and i will +1.

Comment: This is it! The simplicity and function are exactly what I was looking for! As mentioned from Brandon above, this only works if the strings are together. It is doable, but if there is any way to set up [if(text.find("these other words") != std::string::npos)] so that it runs as long as certain words are present. Such as [if(text.find(("fork")&&("chair")&&("words")) != std::string::npos)] Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

A more advanced solution requires function pointers or function objects and a table.

**Function Pointer**
A function pointer is a pointer to a function.  When the pointer is dereferenced, the function is called.

Function pointer syntax is made most useful by employing a `typedef`:

```
typedef void (*Processing_Function_Type)(const std::string& parameter);
```

The above `typedef` declares a pointer to a function that takes a constant string reference and returns nothing.  Consider this an interface definition.

**The Lookup Table**
With strings, `case` statements can't be used.  The `if-elseif` ladders are difficult to follow and may lead to execution errors.  So let's put the information into a table.

```
struct Table_Entry
{
  std::string text;
  Processing_Function_Type p_processing_function; // Pointer to processing function
};

// Some function declarations
void Process_one(const std::string);
void Process_two(const std::string);

// The table
const Table_Entry lookup_table[] =
{
  {"thisword", Process_one},
  {"also maybe these words", Process_two},
};
const unsigned int table_entry_count =
    sizeof(lookup_table) / sizeof(lookup_table[0]);
```

**The Lookup Engine**
A nice benefit to lookup tables is that you don't change the search engine when adding more rows to the table.  With `if` statements, you have to add a new `if` statement for each new item.

```
void Parse_And_Execute(const std::string& text)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < table_entry_count; ++i)
  {
    if (text.find(lookup_table[i].text) != std::string::npos)
    {
      // The text is found, now execute the function.
      (lookup_table[i]p_processing_function)(text);  // Pass the text string

      // Or pass the key text:
      // (lookup_table[i]p_processing_function)(lookup_table[i].text);

      // Exit the loop
      break;
  }
}
```

**Alternative: use `std::map`**
Another alternative is to use `std::map`.
In this case the map would be declared as:

```
  typedef std::map<std::string, Processing_Function_Type> Functional_Dictionary;
```

The next step would be to search the map and if the key exists, dereference the function pointer.

Comment: Interesting. Definitely more complex, however I understand quite a bit. Going to take time to look over the parts I don't know, but the use of the table is a clever idea. Might use it in the future when I get a strong understanding of the details. Thank you!